# cakephp - Call shell from component

Tags: php, shell, cakephp

How can I call a shell from my component.

Here is my shell

```
<?php 
   class PrintShell extends AppShell {

    function main()
    {
        App::import(‘Component’, ‘BusinessLogic’);
        $businessLogic = & new BusinessLogicComponent();
        $businessLogic->initialize();
        $settings = $businessLogic->senReminderEmail();
        // senReminderEmail Mail function is defined in my Controller/Components/BusinessLogicComponent.php File
    }

}
?>
```

I dont want it to call using commands.
How can I do this.Any help
Does this makes sense?

Comment: What do you mean by this? "call a shell from my component". Shells are used for cronjob stuff or any action you want to be run trough console not component. What do you want to do? Doesn't make scene to me..

Comment: You can't run shell from front in direct way.

Answer (score -1):

you want to call shell 
i think, do you want to use cron job in cakephp..?
mostly appshell used to work with cron job and i have also faced out this one and i had not used appshell i set up my cron job from godaddy server and putted all files in webroot folder which may operate during cron time so i just verified..dear..

Comment: Is it answer or an other question?

Comment: I dont want a cron job.I want make run commands from my component.How can i do this.I dont know whether this makes some sense.please any other alternative solution is appreciated